# Standalone External QGIS Application using python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I am creating a standalone external Application of QGIS using python and i am following the tutorial mentioned in the link http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/workshops/foss4g2007_qgis0.9_workshop_en.pdf

I compiled my UI as well as the resource file and also set QGISHOME , Python path and the path for the dll files. And run my py file using OSGeo4W Shell. just the python file is running and nothing appears other than that what is expected (Viewer should opens, browse for shape files, and do some basic actions like zoom in, zoom out, pan etc.). There is no any error message also. The code is very lengthy to share here.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error message as text in a code block instead of a screen shot

Comment: @ Luke: Edited as you recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without creating a QT application in the main function I directly called the function that initiates the QGIS libraries. That was the problem. Now it got solved after making changes.